# Additional questions for Cranium?

Tags: expansions

My group of friends really enjoys playing Cranium, but we played it so often that we all more or less memorized the questions and have plans for all the activities.

Is there more content available for Cranium, and if so, where can it be found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are booster packs for Cranium that add more cards for each category. For example, this [set](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000028F51) and this [set](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000063XNO).

You could also check out the [Cranium WOW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000Q7I6VW) edition. It has a whole new set of cards. I've played this version and a lot of the red cards seemed easier than the original version of the game.